# Filtering rows by multiple regex conditions

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to filter various rows in my data frame by the following expressions. The first two are working according to regex101 but I can't get number 3 and four to work properly.

1. Between two `:` : `DTM+137:20180101:102`-> `^DTM.*\:(.*?)\:` -> `20180101`
2. Between two `:` : `QTY+113:3:PCE` -> `^QTY.*\:(.*?)\:` -> `3`
3. After second `+` and subsequent `:` :`UNH+10870+DELFOR:D:96A:UN` -> `???` -> `DELFOR`
4. Everything after second `+` : `PIA+1+TC_5504_00_312010_0010+50100 AA40 2.8t Type 4466 G` -> `???` -> `TC_5504_00_312010_0010+50100 AA40 2.8t Type 4466 G`

Further, I would appreciate any comments whether the first samples are sound and solid to continuously provide the same output. The intended use will be in a `R` script, thus I still need to escape some of the characters later on.

EDIT:
Accidentally, I forgot one line of expression:

5. Everything after second last `+`: `UNB+UNOC:3+4399901362247+_GLN_Company__+180101:0050+10870`-> `???` -> `180101:0050+10870`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(stringr)

x = "DTM+137:20180101:102"
str_extract(x, "(?<=:)(.*?)(?=:)")
# [1] "20180101"

y = "QTY+113:3:PCE"
str_extract(y, "(?<=:)(.*?)(?=:)")
# [1] "3"

z = "UNH+10870+DELFOR:D:96A:UN"
str_extract(z, "(?<=\\+)([A-Z].*?)(?=:)")
# [1] "DELFOR"

u = "PIA+1+TC_5504_00_312010_0010+50100 AA40 2.8t Type 4466 G"
str_extract(u, "(?<=\\+)([A-Z].*)")
# [1] "TC_5504_00_312010_0010+50100 AA40 2.8t Type 4466 G"
```